# can't start minio server in ubuntu with systemctl start minio

Tags: minio

I configured a minio instance server on the ubuntu 18.04 with the guide from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-object-storage-server-using-minio-on-ubuntu-18-04.

after the installation, the server failed to start with the command "sudo systemctl start minio", the error is saying :

```
root@iZbp1icuzly3aac0dmjz9aZ:~# sudo systemctl status  minio
● minio.service - MinIO
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/minio.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-12-23 17:11:56 CST; 4s ago
     Docs: https://docs.min.io
  Process: 9085 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/minio server $MINIO_OPTS $MINIO_VOLUMES (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 9084 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c if [ -z "${MINIO_VOLUMES}" ]; then echo "Variable MINIO_VOLUMES not set in /etc/default/minio"; exit 1; fi (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 9085 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 23 17:11:56 iZbp1icuzly3aac0dmjz9aZ systemd[1]: minio.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 23 17:11:56 iZbp1icuzly3aac0dmjz9aZ systemd[1]: minio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 23 17:11:56 iZbp1icuzly3aac0dmjz9aZ systemd[1]: minio.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 23 17:11:56 iZbp1icuzly3aac0dmjz9aZ systemd[1]: minio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Dec 23 17:11:56 iZbp1icuzly3aac0dmjz9aZ systemd[1]: Stopped MinIO.
Dec 23 17:11:56 iZbp1icuzly3aac0dmjz9aZ systemd[1]: minio.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 23 17:11:56 iZbp1icuzly3aac0dmjz9aZ systemd[1]: minio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 23 17:11:56 iZbp1icuzly3aac0dmjz9aZ systemd[1]: Failed to start MinIO.
It looks like the reason is the Variable MINIO_VOLUMES not set in /etc/default/minio.
```

However, I double check the file from /etc/default/minio

```
MINIO_ACCESS_KEY="minioadmin"
MINIO_VOLUMES="/usr/local/share/minio/"
MINIO_OPTS="-C /etc/minio --address localhost:9001"
MINIO_SECRET_KEY="minioadmin"
I have set the value MINIO_VOLUMES.
```

I tried to start manually with minio server --address :9001 /usr/local/share/minio/, it works.

now I don't know what goes wrong with starting the minio server by using the systemctl start minio

Comment: Please follow https://github.com/minio/minio-service/tree/master/linux-systemd/distributed

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend sticking to the [official documentation](https://docs.min.io/minio/baremetal/installation/deploy-minio-distributed.html#capacity-based-planning) wherever possible. It's intended for distributed deployments but the only real change is that your `MINIO_VOLUMES` will be for a single node/drive.

I would recommend trying a combination of things here:

1. Review `minio.service` and ensure the user/group exists
2. Review file path permissions on the `MINIO_VOLUMES` value

Now for the why:

My guess without seeing further logs (`journalctl -u minio` would have been helpful here) is that this is a combination of two things:

- the `minio.service` user/group doesn't have rwx permissions on the `/usr/local/share/minio` path,
- you are missing an environment variable we recently introduced to prevent users from pointing at their root drive (this was intended as a safety measure, but somewhat complicates these kinds of smaller setups).

Take a look at [these lines](https://github.com/minio/minio-service/blob/master/linux-systemd/minio.service#L11-L13) in the `minio.service` file - I'm assuming that is what you are using based on the instructions in the DO guide.

If you `ls -al /usr/local/share/minio` I would venture it has ROOT permissions for user and group and limited write access if any.

Hope this helps - for further troubleshooting having at least 10-20 lines from `journalctl` is invaluable, as it would show the actual error and not just the final quit message.

Answer (score 1):

#### Explanation:

1. `Variable MINIO_VOLUMES not set in /etc/default/minio` is NOT the error.
2. You have to look at the logs with `journalctl -u minio` command.

#### Possible Solution:

After you looked at the logs, you can see things like:

```
Sep 04 08:28:37 asus minio[43217]: Error: unable to create (/Volumes/data1/.minio.sys/tmp) file access denied, drive may be faulty please investigate (*fmt.wrapError)
Sep 04 08:28:37 asus minio[43217]:        6: internal/logger/logger.go:258:logger.LogIf()
Sep 04 08:28:37 asus minio[43217]:        5: cmd/prepare-storage.go:95:cmd.bgFormatErasureCleanupTmp()
Sep 04 08:28:37 asus minio[43217]:        4: cmd/xl-storage.go:250:cmd.newXLStorage()
Sep 04 08:28:37 asus minio[43217]:        3: cmd/object-api-common.go:61:cmd.newStorageAPI()
Sep 04 08:28:37 asus minio[43217]:        2: cmd/format-erasure.go:673:cmd.initStorageDisksWithErrors.func1()
Sep 04 08:28:37 asus minio[43217]:        1: internal/sync/errgroup/errgroup.go:123:errgroup.(*Group).Go.func1()
Sep 04 08:28:37 asus minio[43217]: Unable to use the drive /Volumes/data1: drive access denied
Sep 04 08:28:37 asus minio[43217]: Unable to use the drive /Volumes/data2: drive access denied
Sep 04 08:28:37 asus minio[43217]: Unable to use the drive /Volumes/data3: drive access denied
Sep 04 08:28:37 asus minio[43217]: Unable to use the drive /Volumes/data4: drive access denied
```

If that is the case and depending on your volumes, you can fix it like this:

```
sudo chown -R minio-user. /Volumes/data1 && sudo chmod u+rxw /Volumes/data1
sudo chown -R minio-user. /Volumes/data2 && sudo chmod u+rxw /Volumes/data2
sudo chown -R minio-user. /Volumes/data3 && sudo chmod u+rxw /Volumes/data3
sudo chown -R minio-user. /Volumes/data4 && sudo chmod u+rxw /Volumes/data4
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this first journalctl -u minio to see the error log.
Read the error and fix it.

[example of error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBmsQ.png)